# Could not load file or assembly '...dll'

Tags: c#, docker, dll, arm, x86-64

I have a problem and I can't get any further.
I have an Edge Box with Docker installed. Now I want to run a C# application on this Edge Box.
The Edge Box itself does not have an Internet connection, which is why I create the Docker image locally on the PC (AMD architecture) and then save it as a .tar file and then import it to the Edge Box via Portainer. However, when I run this image on the Edge Box, I get the error message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/Name.dll'. The System cannot find the file specified.
```

As already mentioned, the PC has an AMD architecture, the Edge Box an arm32 architecture. So I create the image like this:

```
docker build --platform=linux/arm/v7 -t imagename .
```

I´ve tried it as a dotnet and as a dotnet Core application.

I wrote the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env

COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Name.dll"]
```

I´ve tried many Base Images there. For example:
`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0`

Is it even possible to run a C# (.net / .net Core) application on an arm32 architecture?

I used many hours for this problem and I have no more idea how to solve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: How did you publish the application?

Comment: also, copying the application to the root of the docker image is probably not ideal.

Comment: The not found assembly is the one you called from the docker file via Entrypoint? Currently in your question they are dfferent.

Comment: Yeah Im sorry. The dll not found is the same as in the entrypoint. Name.dll. Ill edit it fast! sorry.

Comment: I published the application in visual studio. So right Click on the project, publish, publish folder and right after I got those new folders (bin/release/net6.0/publish . Is that wrong?

Comment: Maybe, depends on what options you selected. Since that feature in visual studio is a bit error-prone, I suggest using the command line instead. `dotnet publish name.csproj --runtime linux-arm --self-contained`

Comment: Okay, yes I didnt publish it over command line. I can try that! Do I have the correct Base Image? And the Dockerfile looks good aswell in general? Is it even possible to run a dotnet application on arm architecture?